# Escaping & (special chars) in MySql or PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The string-

```
<object width="480" height="385"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/ebopIWPoXI0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/ebopIWPoXI0?fs=1&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="385"></embed></object>
```

What gets stored in the database -

```
<object width=\"480\" height=\"385\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/ebopIWPoXI0?fs=1
```

Already using - `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which doesn't help with the `&`:

```
$_POST['desc'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
mysql_query('INSERT INTO user_showcase( title, description, user_id, date_n_time) VALUES( "'.$_POST['title'].'", "'.$_POST['desc'].'", "'.$_SESSION['uid'].'", NOW())') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
```

The HTML -

```
<textarea id="desc_in" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `&` for MySQL.

Comment: You don't tell us how you are storing it there. I can't think of anything on the MySQL side which should react to the &. It is bizarre to use HTML entities in a URL - that should probably be URI escaped (as in another question). But I don't see what relevance that would have to this problem.

Comment: Hmmm.. then what could be the problem here?

Comment: Its a text data type ...

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa: So the data type is actually [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)?

Comment: How are you testing what's actually stored? Are you using HeidiSQL or another GUI client?

Comment: I'm using PHPmyAdmin,
@gumbo- yes it is actually TEXT

Comment: Then it's time to see some real code. Can you put together a small code snippet that reproduces the problem?

Comment: i've edited it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string() **is** the proper mechanism if you are using the legacy MySQL library. If you are getting all those additional backslashes it's probably because your PHP environment is very old. Run `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and find the directives that start with `magic_`:

```
magic_quotes_gpc
magic_quotes_runtime
magic_quotes_sybase
```

Ideally, they should all be disabled. If you run PHP as Apache module, you can change it in an `.htaccess` file:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag magic_quotes_runtime Off
php_flag magic_quotes_sybase Off
```

If you run PHP as CGI, you'll probably have a custom `php.ini` file somewhere in your account.

As already mentioned, `&` is not a special char for MySQL.

## Answer to updated question

The standard string delimiter in SQL is the single quote, not the double quote:

```
SELECT 'I am a string';
```

Comment: I turned those off, but i'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure it's not *you* the one that's injecting the backslashes?

Comment: After turning the magic quotes off , the backslashes disappear but the data stored in the database still terminates at the '&amp'.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using a parameterized query

Comment: You seriously downvoted me because you're too stupid to know what a parameterized query is? Wow, I remember now why I don't deal with PHP devs...